# How to calculate the number of days one can stay in the Schengen area?

Tags: schengen, visa-expiration, day-counting

Valid for: Schengenstater (Issued by Sweden)
valid From: 26-09-16 to 16-10-16
Type of Visa: C
Number of Entries: 1
Duration of Stay: 6 days

1st entry in Greece on 10-10-16 and exit on 13-10-16
2nd entry in Belgium on 13-10-16 and exit on 14-10-16
3rd entry in Norway on 14-10-16 and exit on 16-10-16

My stay at Schengen countries in total of 6 Days (from 10-10-16 to 16-10-16). This is how the calculation or I am over staying? Please Advise.

Comment: That's seven days, because you were present in the Schengen area on October 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th, 15th, and 16th.

Comment: My entry on 10th by 17:15hrs. Exit on 16th 13:10hrs. Technicaly i am not over stayed if the hrs added to my trip. I'll be over stay if i stay back over 17:15hrs time. Am i right/wrong?

Comment: It is not a matter of no more than 6*24 hours, but of being in the Schengen area on no more than 6 days.

Comment: Did you give the consulate the same itinerary? If yes, then contact the consulate immediately.

Comment: @SRK You're wrong, the number of hours doesn't matter. October 10-16 is 7 days as phoog explained. It's the same if you enter on 01:00 on the 10th and leave at 23:00 on the 16th or if you enter at 23:00 and leave at 01:00.

Comment: So I should exit Schengen area on 15-10-16. Am I right?. But are some calculation still stay me on doubt. I go through the Schengen calculator website (adambard.github.io/schengencalc). It gave me result like this. 1st entry in Greece on 10-10-16 and exit on 13-10-16 - 4 days, 2nd entry in Belgium on 13-10-16 and exit on 14-10-16 – 2 days, 3rd entry in Norway on 14-10-16 and exit on 15-10-16 – 2days, Total days it shows 8. This is how the other way it’s calculated. Let me know what is the exact day whether its 6/8 days?

Comment: Are you actually planning to exit the Schengen area on the 13th and the 14th both? It doesn't matter for the day calculation, but unless you have flights with a change of planes outside Schengen, traveling from Greece to Belgium or from Belgium to Norway would not entail leaving or entering the Schengen area.

Comment: @SRK: The "Schengen calculator" you link to is not the official one. It appears that the unofficial calculator you use does not correctly deal with situations where you exit the area and then reenter on the same day. Such days should not count twice -- what matters is whether _at any time on that date_ you have been inside the Schengen area or not.

Comment: As I understand it, you will enter the Schengen area on the 10th and exit on the 16th, traveling to several countries within Schengen during that time, but not exiting until the end of that time. Any day you are in Schengen for one second counts as a day, so that is seven days: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16. If you gave the consulate your itinerary and they issued the visa this way, then you need to contact them right away to have it corrected. Otherwise, you should follow the original itinerary you gave them and ensure you only stay six days.

Answer (score 5):

### The Schengen Day Counting Methodology

There is no such thing as hours in the methodology (or any time interval less than hours). The smallest unit of measurement is a day.

So if you are in the zone for 1 second, even one instant, that's reckoned as a day. And that day is reckoned as 'spent leave' against any day count restrictions given to you by the post that issued your visa.

The same methodology is used for non-visa nationals (i.e., people who can enter the zone without a visa). When they enter the zone, regardless of the time of day, one *full* day is consumed against the standard 90 day allowance. When they exit, even at 1 minute past midnight, it's another full day consumed.

In your case you are visa-national with a 6 day allowance. The day you enter and the day you leave will consume 2 full days. It doesn't matter that you will arrive in the evening, it's one full calendar day spent against your allowance.

### Other cases

The UK uses the same methodology as Schengen for the purposes of determining whether or not a person can qualify for citizenship or permanent residence. Entry days and exit days are reckoned as full days inside the UK.  The [standard-visitor-visa](/questions/tagged/standard-visitor-visa) provides explicit start and end dates and this obviates the need for day counting.  For people who do not need a visa, the UK will issue an entry certificate (in reality a passport stamp) of 6 months.  There is no 'official' method for what constitutes a 'month' and this injects ambiguity into how a 'month' should be interpreted.  The ambiguity is deliberate so that it can be favourable either to the traveller or to the Border Force depending on the situation.

USA? Canada? Japan? (Community Wiki)

Comment: So I should exit Schengen area on 15-10-16. Am I right?. 

But are some calculation still stay me on doubt. I go through the Schengen calculator website (http://adambard.github.io/schengencalc/). It gave me result like this.

1st entry in Greece on 10-10-16 and exit on 13-10-16 - 4 days,
2nd entry in Belgium on 13-10-16 and exit on 14-10-16 – 2 days,
3rd entry in Norway on 14-10-16 and exit on 15-10-16 – 2days,

Total days it shows 8. This is how the other way it’s calculated. 
Let me know what is the exact day whether its 6/8 days?.

Comment: @SRK no, the answer is clear enough and does not need refinement in comments. If you cannot figure it out, hire a professional, sorry

Comment: Your lengthy answer not help me to the point. 
@'If you cannot figure it out, hire a professional' it's none of your business. This is the forum everyone put forth questions. 
If you’re not comfort with my question, simply ignore. I am not interested to read useless comment anyone does.

Comment: @SRK, this is not a forum. Also if you want to complain, please take it to META at http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/ so that the higher ups can have a look.  Thanks.

Comment: @SRK, I am somewhat late to the party here, but let me point out you are probably _not_ exiting Schengen on your itinerary unless for some reason your journeys Greece-Belgium and Belgium-Norway involve flight connections in London. Direct flights, or connections in another Schengen country (e.g., Germany) don't entail an exit. If you _are_ changing planes in the UK, you have a _big_ problem, which is that your visa is _single entry._ A lesser problem is you never visited Sweden, which issued the visa. This may complicate subsequent visa requests, or even result in denial of initial entry.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the official Schengen calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm) to calculate the remaining days to stay in Schengen area. It is user friendly and gives accurate results.