# Calculating Schengen visa validity

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, visa-expiration

I applied for a Schengen visa for me and my family, and in the application I wrote my date of entry 14-03-2019 and date of exit 29-03-2019. I even bought air tickets for the same dates. My visa arrived and shows valid for 15 days, date of entry is 14-03-2019 until 29-03-2019.

I’m worried as as per calculation, if I enter on 14-03-2019 then my 15 days would be completed on 28-3-2019. But when I ask the VSF Global agent in Riyadh, he told they will calculate days from the next day so you will finish your days on 29 so nothing to worried about. Do I need to be worried?

Added from what was posted in an answer:
I applied Switzerland from Riyadh KSA.

Comment: The VFS agent is wrong.  You must get the visa corrected.   Which country did you apply to?

Comment: In your application form, what did you put in box 25, "duration of the intended stay or transit / indicate number of days"?  If you put *15,* then you probably have to either change your flight or apply for a new visa.  If you put *16,* then you may be able to get them to correct your visa without having to submit a new application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/79214/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-one-can-stay-in-the-schengen-area

Answer (score 16):

The VFS agent is wrong.  You can check this at the [official Schengen calculator](https://ec.europa.eu/assets/home/visa-calculator/calculator.htm?lang=en).  If you enter your dates and click "calculate," you will see that it counts this as 16 days.

The method of counting days of presence is specified in the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407), Article 6(2):

> ...the date of entry shall be considered as the first day of stay on the territory of the Member States and the date of exit shall be considered as the last day of stay on the territory of the Member States....

There is another consideration, however.  The Schengen visa application form asks the applicant, at number 25, to indicate a specific duration of stay.  If you entered *15* for this item, then it is *your mistake* and you are unlikely to get it corrected except by submitting a fresh application and paying the application fee again.  This still probably better than changing your travel plans.

If you in fact entered the correct figure *16* for that item, you should file a formal complaint with VFS via their [customer experience page](https://www.vfsglobal.ch/switzerland/saudiarabia/customer_experience.html).  Explain that the 15-day visa is not adequate for the proposed trip and does not match the 16 days you requested in your application, and that you would like to have the visa corrected.  I would probably mention both the Schengen visa calculator and Art. 6(2) of the Schengen Borders Code.

If VFS formally rejects your complaint, you should try to escalate it to the Swiss authorities.  If VFS will not bring it to the attention of the Swiss authorities, you can try to find a way of complaining to the Swiss embassy in Saudi Arabia, but I was not able to find one.  There *is,* however, contact information for the [State Secretariat for Migration](https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/saudi-arabia/en/home/visa/information-contacts.html) in Switzerland.  These people, at least, should understand that your proposed trip requires a 16-day visa.  If you explain your problem to them, they may be able to help you solve it, whether by instructing VFS to accept your complaint or by other means.